# Does biztalk have Service Packs? Or just Cumulative updates?

Tags: biztalk, servicepacks

Does biztalk have Service Packs? Or just Cumulative updates?
I am unable to see any service packs after 2009

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BizTalk only has cumulative updates, they do not have concept of Service Packs, I believe they changed the model somewhere in 2006. You should look for latest cumulative updates.

Here is the full list
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2555976

Answer (score 0):

The BizTalk Server Product Group only ships Cumulative Updates.  However, they mostly follow the Service Pack paradigm as a CU will contain all fixes from all previous CU's.